# Why is Webpack generating 2 chunks per dynamic import()?

Tags: webpack, code-splitting, code-splitting-async

I've started using some dynamic `import()` statements like so

```
import(/* webpackChunkName: "chart" */'./Chart')
```

the problem is that Webpack generates 2 new chunks for this: **`chart.js`** (which is almost empty) and **`vendors~chart.js`** (which actually has everything that I expected to be in one new chunk).

My config has nothing fancy in it. I have only one named entry called `client` and that was my only bundle before using the dynamic require.
This happens for both development and production mode.
I'm using Webpack ver. 4.8.1

**Any ideas how to achieve just one new chunk?** I don't want the client to make 2 requests instead of one.

Comment: "which is almost empty", what is inside of that?

Comment: That might have been misleading. What I meant was that there's a source code of my component in it, which is very lightweight (2KB gziped) compared to external library dependency (which webpack put in `vendors-chart.js and is about 90 KB gzipped)

Answer (score 4):

I found two (imperfect) ways to avoid that.

1. If your app have a single entry, you can remove the `vendors` cache group altogether since this vendor group is designed for multi-entry apps.

   ```
   optimization: {
     splitChunks: {
       cacheGroups: {
         vendors: false, // not needed for a single entry app
       },
     },
   },
   ```
2. you can use [`webpack.optimize.MinChunkSizePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/min-chunk-size-plugin/) that will bundle you small chunk to another one, albeit not necessarily with the best optimized option.

Comment: The first solution worked great for me, but I had to change `vendors` to `defaultVendors`, see https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#optimizationsplitchunks